# Add OpenMP support to mex file compile from C file with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, matlab, openmp, mex

I am new to parallel programming and I've come across an issue with the OpenMP library. I got it tested in a visual studio win 32 console application with simple code:

```
int main(){
omp_set_num_threads(2);
#pragma omp parallel
    { 
       int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
       long tmp;
       if(tid == 0){ for (int i = 0;i<10000;i++){ tmp = ((i*999)*90000)*((i*999)*90000) }
       if(tid == 1){ for (int i = 0;i<10000;i++){ tmp = ((i*999)*90000)*((i*999)*90000) }
    }
}
```

The code is running in parallel and if I run it without OpenMP it runs 2 time longer.
Now, in MATLAB I can run `.mex` files which are C files that are compiled to run in MATLAB, and you need to add the `/openmp` compile flag in the file for the specific compiler. Since I am working in Visual Studio 2010 the file that needs to be modified is `msvc100opts.bat` and there I am adding `/openmp` to the compile flags. When I am benchmarking I get bad results and it is unstable. I've read tons of guides that didn't help me. How can I reliably use OpenMP directives in `.mex` files in MATLAB?

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific regarding "bad results" and "unstable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extended comment rather than an answer, and to be honest I'm not sure what your real question is anyway ...

What you've shown us isn't parallelised.  It may behave as if it is but it isn't (not quite).  You have defined an OpenMP parallel region, so every line inside the block

```
#pragma omp parallel
    { 
     ...
    }
```

is run by each thread.  Now, each thread will encounter both `if` statements and act appropriately so you may think that your program is running in parallel, and you may be right, but you've done the parallelisation, not OpenMP.

You've omitted a parallelisation worksharing directive such as `for`. For OpenMP parallelisation you have to write something like (I haven't checked either the syntax or the semantics of this):

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    { 
       for (int i = 0;i<10000;i++){ tmp = ((i*999)*90000)*((i*999)*90000) }
    }
```

Note:

1. I've included a worksharing directive, `for`.
2. With OpenMP there is (almost) never a need for the programmer to concern herself with thread ids.  As you've written it your program would require rewriting and recompilation to use any number of threads other than two.  Worse yet, you've done the grunt work of parallelisation; if that's what you want to do go right ahead, but you scarcely need OpenMP for that.
3. The amount of work done inside the parallel region is tiny. In fact a really good compiler might spot `tmp` isn't used outside the parallel region and optimise away the entire loop. You won't be able to draw any useful conclusions about the performance of the parallel program *vs* the performance of a serial version, not even after you fix the issues.

As for problems with compiling MEX files using OpenMP on Windows, I have nothing to suggest, but I'll point out that even the most recent editions of the MS C and C++ compiler don't implement OpenMP after v2.0

Comment: +1 thank you for sharing your knowledge tough it is nor helping with the mex issue.

Comment: My favourite search engine turns up a ton of results for *openmp in mex files*, I expect yours will too. From your question it seems likely that your program is compiling correctly with OpenMP but not behaving as you expect. If it is not compiling correctly augment your question with the compilation errors and warnings.

Comment: if i was able to solve this with my search engine i wouldnt ask here. it is really easy to say "My favourite search engine turns up a ton of results" well... do you think i didnt tried?

Comment: Ooh, snippy, I'm wounded.  Despite your efforts you weren't able to find, it seems, a correct OpenMP example to study.  Try https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/optaps/common/optaps_par_mpex.htm